# Not in and not like

Tags: mysql

Kindly let me know whats wrong with the following: (Returned no rows)

```
 Select * 
 from class 
 where sem NOT LIKE concat('%',(Select sem_id from semester ),'%')
```

I asked this cause the following trick is working fine: (Returned 8 rows)

```
 Select * 
 from class 
 where sem NOT IN (Select sem_id from semester )
```

Comment: Any error message? Perhaps the r-arg to `like` cannot be an expression

Comment: What does concat returns and whats the type of sem?

Comment: your concat makes no sense to me; try select concat('%',(Select sem_id from semester ),'%') and see what it returns

Comment: Try to give an alias to concat and pass it to condition

Comment: @akonsu I did not like part by joining the table and then simply apply not like but it will not display anything, also my idea of concat was `%LIKE%` (Values being returned by query)

Comment: `Select sem_id …` will return multiple rows, not a single value, but MySQL expects a single value

Comment: also look into mysql's `RLIKE` function...seems like it's what you're trying to do!  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need join syntax for this.  Presumably, you are trying to find classes whose semester is not like any in the table.  First find the ones that do match, and then filter these out using `having`:

```
Select c.*
from class c left outer join
     semester s
     on c.sem like concat('%', s.sem_id, '%')
group by c.class_id
having max(s.sem_id) is null  -- there are no matching semesters
```

You can eliminate the `group by` by writing the query like this:

```
 Select c.*
 from class 
 where not exists (select s.sem_id
                   from semester s
                   where class.sem like ('%', s.sem_id, '%')
                   limit 1
                  )
```

Comment: can i make comparison like this `where sem and year not in (select seme,yr from class)` ? if not then how can i make such comparison

Comment: To compare two things, use the correlated subquery version and put them in the `where` clause in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks alot, problem is being solved i forgot to delete values

Answer (score 0):

They are two different queries, although both of them are odd. I would suspect every class to have a semester. If you would have proper foreign key constraints, `sem` could at most be `null`, in which case your query would become:

```
select * 
from class 
where sem is null
```

But the second query should work and should return all classes that have a value in `sem` that is not in the table `semester`.

The first query however, will fail as soon as there are more than one records in `semester`. Also, it does a string comparison on a (supposedly) numeric field. All in all, that first query doesn't make sense.